# how to use zip.write() on directories using a relative path in python?

Tags: python, zip, relative-path, bytesio

I am wanting to add explicit entries for the directories in my zipfile. For example my zipfile includes:

`assets/images/logo.png`

When in reality I need it to include:

```
assets/
assets/images/
assets/images/logo.png
```

So my question is, how do I add the directories as explicit entries using relative paths? I tried to use `zip.write(relative/path/to/directory)` but it says it can't find the directory, since its a relative path. It works when I put

`/Users/i510118/Desktop/Engineering/kit-dev-portal-models/src/kit_devportal_models/static_data/static_extension/created_extnsn_version_update2/assets/images/logo.png`

inside of zipfile.write(), but I need it to just be the relative path, which is just

`assets/images/logo.png`

is this possible?

Here is my full code

```
        buf = io.BytesIO()
    zipObj = zipfile.ZipFile(buf, "w")
    extension_folder = "created_extnsn_version_update2"
    with zipObj:
        # Iterate over all the files in directory
        for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path_to_extension_directory):
            # If the folder is not the root folder the extension is in
            if not folderName.endswith(extension_folder):
                folder = folderName.split(f"{extension_folder}/", 1)[1]
            else:
                folder = ''
            for filename in filenames:
                # create complete filepath of file in directory
                filePath = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folderName, filename), path_to_extension_directory)
                with open(f"{folderName}/{filename}", 'rb') as file_data:
                    bytes_content = file_data.read()
                    # Add folder to zip if its not the root directory
                    if folder:
                        zipObj.write(folder)
                    # Add file to zip
                    zipObj.writestr(filePath, bytes_content)
                    # edit zip file to have all permissions
                    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(buf, mode='a')
                    info = zipfile.ZipInfo(f"{folderName}/{filename}")
                    info.external_attr = 0o777 << 16
                    zf.writestr(info, f"{folderName}/{filename}")

    # Rewind the buffer's file pointer (may not be necessary)
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf.read()
```

Please let me know if you need more information!

Comment: You should take a look at pathlib(https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From code stolen from [add empty directory using zipfile?](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-June/205859.html)

```py
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')

folders = [
    "assets/",
    "assets/images/",
    ]

for n in folders:
    zfi = zipfile.ZipInfo(n)
    zf.writestr(zfi, '')

zf.write('logo.png', 'assets/images/logo.png')

zf.close()

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'r')

for i in zf.infolist():
    print(f"is_dir: {i.is_dir()}; filename: {i.filename}")

zf.close()
```